# ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = numeric

Tags: postgresql, jpa

So I keep getting the title error. The string I am using to create the query is,

```
  select p from Product p where  p.productType.productTypeId in (:productTypeIds)
```

And here is a clip of the java

```
    List<Long>partTerminologyIds = getProducTypeds(partTerminologys);
    ..........................................................................
    query.setParameter("partTerminologyIds", productTypeIds);
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error, ane yes partTerminolgyId in my database is a numeric 18.

Any ideas???

Comment: You have the arguments in `query.setParameter()` the other way round. Should be `query.setParameter("productTypeIds", partTerminologyIds)`. (You also need a space after `List<Long>` :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the end it ended up being that a "foreign key" was a string in one table and an numeric in the other. I rebuilt the database with new scripts and did not reverse engineer the new database.

Answer (score 1):

This query is invalid:

```
select p from Product p where  p.productType.productTypeId in (:productTypeIds)
```

Do you mean:

```
SELECT p FROM product p WHERE p.productTypeId IN (:productTypeIds)
```

Or rather:

```
SELECT * FROM product p WHERE p.productTypeId IN (:productTypeIds)
```

And if so, what is the data type of `productTypeId` in your query. Please clarify.

Comment: I know this is kinda late but product type is another table.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Hibernate query. You need to do `query.setParameterList` to specify a collection value, otherwise Hibernate won't know to expand out `:productTypeIds` to a list of placeholders instead of simply binding the list as a serializable blob (which I think is an awful default).

Comment: We are using javax.persistence.TypedQuery which does not have setParameterList. Also I should mention this worked with MySQL

Comment: @user517721: What does and does not work in MySQL retains a certain element of surprise.